# Eigendecomposition of the direct sum of two operator on Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let the (finite dimensional) Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ be the direct sum of $\mathcal{H}_A$ and $\mathcal{H}_B$.

Let $A$ be a linear operator on $\mathcal{H}_A$ and $B$ be a linear operator on $\mathcal{H}_B$.
Let $A = \sum_j \lambda_j^A |\psi_j^A\rangle \langle \psi_j^A|$ and $B = \sum_j \lambda_j^B |\psi_j^B \rangle \langle\psi_j^B|$ be the eigendecomposition of the two operators.

What is the eigendecomposition of $A \oplus B$?

From the definition it follows:
$$(A \oplus B) = \sum_j \lambda_j^A |\psi_j^A\rangle \langle \psi_j^A| \oplus \sum_k \lambda_k^B |\psi_k^B \rangle \langle\psi_k^B|$$
and
$$(A \oplus B) = \sum_j \sum_k   (\lambda_j^A |\psi_j^A\rangle \oplus \lambda_k^B |\psi_k^B\rangle)(\langle\psi_j^A| \oplus \langle\psi_k^B|)$$
Not sure, though, if the next step is correct:
$$(A \oplus B) = \sum_j \sum_k \lambda_j^A \lambda_k^B (|\psi_j^A\rangle \oplus |\psi_k^B\rangle)(\langle\psi_j^A| \oplus \langle\psi_k^B|)$$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). (The answer is extremely simple.)

Comment: It’s just the sum of the two eigendecompositions.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for the suggestions. I have clarified the post.

Comment: @DavidGao Thank you! I have added a tentative solution, not sure what properties I can use to unfold the sum of the contributions of A and B into contributions of A\oplus B

Comment: @incud No, direct sum does not distribute over summation. Instead, it’s just the sum of the two eigendecompositions, no distribution whatsoever needed.

Comment: (That is to say, just change the direct sum in your formula for $A \oplus B$ to sum would give you the answer.)

Comment: Thank you, if you want to write the answer below, I will accept it

Comment: $$\begin{align}A \oplus B&= \sum_j \lambda_j^A |\psi_j^A\rangle \langle \psi_j^A| \oplus \sum_k \lambda_k^B |\psi_k^B \rangle \langle\psi_k^B|\\
&=\sum_j \lambda_j^A |\psi_j^A\oplus0_B\rangle \langle\psi_j^A\oplus0_B|+\sum_k \lambda_k^B |0_A\oplus\psi_k^B \rangle \langle0_A\oplus\psi_k^B|
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigendecomposition of $A \oplus B$ is just the sum of the two eigendecompositions, that is,

$$A \oplus B = \sum_j \lambda_j^A | \psi_j^A \rangle \langle \psi_j^A | + \sum_k \lambda_k^A | \psi_k^A \rangle \langle \psi_k^A |$$

Where I identified $H_A$ as a subspace of $H = H_A \oplus H_B$ by $H_A \ni h \mapsto h \oplus 0 \in H_A \oplus H_B$ and similarly identified $H_B$ as a subspace of $H = H_A \oplus H_B$ by $H_B \ni h \mapsto 0 \oplus h \in H_A \oplus H_B$.

To prove the above decomposition is the eigendecomposition, hint: Show that if $\psi_j^A$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $\psi_j^A \oplus 0$ is an eigenvector of $A \oplus B$ with the same eigenvalue. Similarly, if $\psi_k^B$ is an eigenvector of $B$, then $0 \oplus \psi_k^B$ is an eigenvector of $A \oplus B$ with the same eigenvalue. Moreover, if $\{e_j\}$ and $\{f_k\}$ are orthonormal bases of $H_A$ and $H_B$, respectively, then $\{e_j \oplus 0\}_j \cup \{0 \oplus f_k\}_k$ is an orthonormal basis of $H_A \oplus H_B$.